# "один раз рисовали" or "один раз порисовали"?

Tags: значения, вид

What way is correct?:

> Мы уже один раз рисовали.

or

> Мы уже один раз **по**рисовали.

If both are correct, then what are the different shades in meaning?
Is it like "Мы уже один раз порисовали" can have ironical sense?

Comment: Without context, "порисовали" sounds to me like "порисовали и хватит". Actually, and with context too)

Comment: If you mean "we have drawn together once" (pardon my French grammar), basically meaning that it just has happened already, not important when, it's better to say "Мы однажды уже рисовали."

Answer (score 3):

"Мы уже один раз порисовали" может иметь иронический смысл. Похожие конструкции с ироническим смыслом: 1."Идите погуляйте в лесу. - Спасибо, мы уже один раз  погуляли". 2. "Поплавайте в пруду. - Спасибо, мы уже один раз поплавали." (Во во время прогулки и купания случилось что-то неприятное.)

"Мы уже один раз рисовали." Ребёнка, который только-только начал учиться в студии рисования, дедушка спрашивает, как у него идут дела с обучением рисованию. Внук отвечает: "Дела идут хорошо. Мы уже один раз рисовали натюрморт".

"Once we were showing off" can have the ironic sense. Similar design with an ironic sense: 1."Go take a walk in the woods. Thanks, we once walked." 2. "Take a swim in the pond. Thank you, we once had a swim." (While walking and swimming happened something unpleasant.)

"We once drew." A child who has only just started to learn in the Studio of drawing, grandpa asks how's he doing teaching of drawing. The grandson replies: "Things are going well. We once painted still life".

Comment: While `Мы уже один раз порисовали` could have an ironic meaning first thought that comes to my mind would be a dialog like that: 
- (Child) Я хочу ещё порисовать
- (Adult) Мы уже один раз порисовали, а теперь давай сделаем уроки / пойдём погуляем (поделаем что-нибудь ещё, кроме рисования)

Comment: Это возможно. Иронию во фразу "мы уже один раз что-то поделали" обычно добавляют, когда "что-то поделали" закончилось плохо, привело к неприятностям. Например; "Пойди порисуй с натуры стадо коров. Спасибо, я уже один раз порисовал (в стаде была бодливая корова, и эта корова погналась за рисовальщиком).

Comment: I totally understand what you say. It was just a note that it's not the only meaning.

Comment: Ваш пример употребления допустим в разговорном, бытовом употреблении. Но во всех этих "порисовали один или несколько раз (кроме иронического употребления) , поиграли один или несколько раз и т.п. есть отступление от правил русского языка. Строго правильными являются такие варианты: Жена говорит мужу: " Не ходи сегодня на футбольный матч. Побудь дома, поиграй с сыном или порисуй с ним."  Никаких "один раз" или "несколько раз" в этом тексте быть не может.

Comment: "Пооткрывай и позакрывай окно минут пять (в течение пяти минут) - вариант, который с трудом можно себе представить в реальной жизни. Но нарушений русского  языка в нём нет. А вот " пооткрывай и позакрывай несколько раз окно" нарушает правила языка. Правильно - "открой и закрой несколько раз окно."

Comment: Your example of the use is acceptable in colloquial, everyday use. But in all these "showing off one or more times (except in the ironic sense), played one or more times, etc. there is a derogation from the rules of the Russian language is Strictly correct such options are:. The wife tells her husband:" don't go today to the football game , Stay home, play with your son or draw him "No" once "or" several times "in this text can not be.

Comment: "Pootkryli и Požarevac окно в течение примерно пяти минут (пять минут) - вариант, который вряд ли можно себе представить, в реальной жизни, но нарушений русского языка в нем, но .." Pootkryli и Požarevac несколько раз окно "- это не правильно. Правильно -. "открыто и закрыть окно несколько раз."

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for the English speakers:

You can think:

```
We have been [рисовать]-ing smth.
                  \
                    несоверш. вид любого глагола
```

But do not

```
           | порисовали   |
           | нарисовали   |
           | разрисовали  |-ing
           | дорисовали   |
           | пририсовали  |
               [...]
                 \
                  соверш. виды
```

Thus,

```
  Мы уже один раз
 └───────────────┘
   /
  ... нарисовали    | We had to paint out. 
                    | We once painted out.
```

```
                          We had to
                         └─────────┘
                        /
  ... порисовали    | ...  paint a little, paint for a while


  ... разрисовали   | ...  paint with new hatches, 
                           to made a painting excessively large,
                           or mess the painting up

  ... дорисовали    | ...  paint until p. is done,
                           have made the final stroke

  ... пририсовали   | ...  paint-in some more, that not had intented before  

                and so on...
```

Comment: How come совершенный вид is `we had to`? `We had to` means `мы должны были`. I think you are missing translation nuances here.

Comment: @UVV, I stand to be corrected. As an example, I took *'Однажды мы прождали 20 минут столика.'* Here *прождали* is a perfective verb for *ждать.* How can we properly give the perfective aspect of *прождали?*

Comment: with that example you are right. I provided an example in my comment above when perfective aspect doesn't make sense.

Comment: @UVV , Is it better to retain only the Past Simple? Or add Past Simple to it?

Comment: I think Past Simple fits better, although I'm not a language expert ;)